# npm ERR! code ENOENT when adding cordova plugins (cordova deletes the file it's looking for)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-cli, cordova-cli

I am trapped in a somewhat infinite loop of struggles! Please help xD

No matter what phonegap or cordova cli commands I run, cordova seems to delete the very files it's looking for previous to looking for them.

Here are just a few known commands which trigger the error for me:

`$ cordova plugin add <plugin name>`

`$ phonegap plugin add <plugin name>`

`$ cordova platform update <platform name>`

`$ phonegap platform update <platform name>`

`$ cordova platform remove <platform name>`

`$ phonegap platform remove <platform name>`

See below terminal output which shows the output I get when running these commands. I am really unsure why cordova is deleting the very file it's trying to rename before it tries to rename it. Very frustrating!

**Step 1 (check to ensure we have a clean git head and no changes in our working set)**

```
apple@Child-2:~/projects/infiniteinternet/prodmode/prodmode-client-mobile-builds/phonegap * feature-barcode-scanner$ git status
# On branch feature-barcode-scanner
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Step 2 (attempt plugin add)**

```
apple@Child-2:~/projects/infiniteinternet/prodmode/prodmode-client-mobile-builds/phonegap * feature-barcode-scanner$ cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To scan barcodes"
Unmet project requirements for latest version of phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner:
cordova-android (6.2.3 in project, >=6.3.0 required)
Fetching highest version of phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner that this project supports: 6.0.8 (latest is 7.0.0)
Error: Failed to fetch plugin phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@6.0.8 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm WARN cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.5.1 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN cordova-plugin-media-capture@1.2.0 requires a peer of cordova-plugin-file@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN com.prodmod.mobileclient@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN com.prodmod.mobileclient@1.0.0 No license field.

npm ERR! path prodmode-client-mobile-builds/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'prodmode-client-mobile-builds/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js' -> 'prodmode-client-mobile-builds/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/.base64-js.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                 npm update check failed                  │
│           Try running with sudo or get access            │
│           to the local update config store via           │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/apple/.config │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! .npm/_logs/2017-11-10T00_23_21_467Z-debug.log
```

**Step 3 (check git changes caused by the command in step 2)**

Okay, so it failed. Let's find out what happened to the supposed missing file. Well, apparently cordova deleted the file before it looked for it?

```
apple@Child-2:~/projects/infiniteinternet/prodmode/prodmode-client-mobile-builds/phonegap * feature-barcode-scanner$ git status
# On branch feature-barcode-scanner
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/.npmignore
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/.travis.yml
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/LICENSE.MIT
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/README.md
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/base64js.min.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/bower.json
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/lib/b64.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/package.json
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/test/big-data.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/test/convert.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/base64-js/test/url-safe.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/.jshintrc
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/.travis.yml
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/History.md
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/LICENSE
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/Makefile
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/README.md
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/dist/plist-build.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/dist/plist-parse.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/dist/plist.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/examples/browser/index.html
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/index.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/lib/build.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/plist/package.json
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/.npmignore
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/CHANGELOG.md
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/LICENSE
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/README.md
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/Utility.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLAttribute.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLCData.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLComment.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDTDAttList.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDTDElement.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDTDEntity.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDTDNotation.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDeclaration.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDocType.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDocument.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDocumentCB.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLElement.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLNode.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLProcessingInstruction.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLRaw.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLStreamWriter.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLStringWriter.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLStringifier.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLText.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLWriterBase.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/index.js
#   deleted:    node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/simple-plist/node_modules/xmlbuilder/package.json
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix this issue, I'd be super grateful. I'm not sure what caused it or when it took effect, but it's been a couple weeks now that I haven't been able to add plugins to my project.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Environment settings:

```
apple@Child-2:/ $ cordova --version
7.0.1


┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Update available: 7.1.0 (current: 7.0.1) │
│ Run npm install -g cordova to update.    │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘

apple@Child-2:/ $ phonegap --version
7.1.1
apple@Child-2:/ $ node --version
v6.11.1
apple@Child-2:/ $ npm --version
5.4.2
```

Comment: Please post your environment settings: `npm` version, `cordova` version and so on

Comment: @MaximShoustin Environment settings added. Let me know if I missed any.

Comment: try removing node_modules, plugins and platforms folders and run `cordova prepare`. It should restore the platforms and plugins you have in the config.xml and/or package.json

Comment: @DrewT Did you tried clearing npm cache and then try removing ios platform and re-adding it?

Comment: @jcesarmobile ya, I tried that and ended up with the same error and no plugins.

Comment: @Gandhi I did try that and it fails when I try to re=add the platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrmm, so I was able to fix this issue. The discussion in the thread was helpful in leading me to the correct answer without actually solving it.

Here's what I did:

**Step one:** *Update cordova*

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Phonegap was already updated to the latest version but my cordova wasn't.

**Step two**: *Update node and npm*

- I downloaded the compiled source with updated node and npm from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Apparently, after updating these 2 components everything in my app played nice again. At this point it would install into `/plugins` using `phonegap plugin add <plugin name>` but it wasn't propagating the plugin code to Android until I switched the location of the Maven repository.

**Step three:** *Update Maven repository location in build.gradle*

It's not really related to my question but I was able to build the apk permissions as soon as I changed the Maven repository location in `<app root>/phonegap/platforms/android/build.gradle`

Here's what I changed in build.gradle...

My original build.gradle settings:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Which I changed to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
   // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
   }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

After that I was able to build my APK with the correct plugin permissions and use the plugin I added.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know where is a problem in your project but I had similar behavior when I upgraded cordova version and migrated my project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Adding some plugin causes to multiple deletions and all my project *doesn't work*.

I tried a lot of ways to fix it but failed, every time with other Exceptions.

---

So I solved it by creating new project from scratch. Added all plugins one by one and after, copied all `www` folder from old project.

It took me about 30 min but it worth it.

---

*Tip:*   I would put `node_modules` folder to `.gitignore` file. You don't need push all dependancies  to git. Users can clone the project and just run `$ npm install` from root project.

Comment: This was definitely what I was going to try next. Luckily I got it working :o

Comment: @DrewT glad to hear :)